# iphone - device logging

Tags: iphone, debugging

While fiddling around with the settings on the device I'm testing my app on (iPod Touch) I saw a development setting where I can turn logging on.

Does anyone know where this logs to?  I know I can see log statements via the console but I'm hoping to get some log statement when the device isn't connect to my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device will continue logging even when it's not connected to your mac. To see the logs, you need to open Xcode, click the 'Window' menu item, and then 'Organizer'. Then select your device and then select the 'Device Logs' tab. For some reason (for me at least) viewing the logs seems flaky, so if nothing shows up, you may need to completely quit Xcode and restart it.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tested this out yet (I don't have the device with me atm) but it seems like it'll work

Answer (score 0):

You have to go into the Xcode organizer, and click on your device.  The logs will then show up in that window.